# Loading image to ImageView and having it occupy certain space

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-image, android-drawable

I have an image  that is say 45 by 45 pixel and I have it scaled appropriately in the 3 different drawable folder. Now when just load it on the screen it looks bigger than  I want. If  I want it to be smaller, what should I do? I really don't want to change the pixels of the original image. Is there any other solution (like controlling how much space it takes from XML)?

Thank you so much

EDIT: Just more clarification and specific question, How can I make an image occupy say 5% of the screen size irrelevent of the original size of the .png image?

Comment: Please provide more details. Sizes of the image in different folders and your layout.

Comment: Why would different sizes matter in the question, it will be normal scaling that android recommends (1.5 times, 0.5 times..etc). I just wanted to know in general what are the methods used to specify how much an image should occupy? I say I want it to be 5% of the screen width

Comment: Your question wasn't clear. I though it was about something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have `ImageView` occupying 5% by putting it in a `LinearLayout` with another `View`, setting both views `layout_width` to `0dp` and `layout_weight` to `5` and `95` appropriately.

When doing so I would also suggest using 9-patch to not have weirdly looking stretches.

Answer (score 0):

You can not specify what percent of screen should be occupied by the image.
You can do one thing. Specify the different dimension in values folders and specify size there.